# sculpting Clay strip brush mirror issue

Tags: sculpting, mirror, sculpt, brushes, sculpt-mode

[image]

I have such strange problem when draw with clay strip brush a "circle shapes" (on the left) with mirror enabled. Not sure know if it was like this before, I just noticed this. How can I fix that?
I tried recalculating normals and symmetrizing the sphere.

Comment: I also tried creating other objects and tried on them - same issue

Comment: May be nothing to do with your problem, but why are you using 4.0.0 alpha when 4.0.1 is the current release version of Blender?

Comment: I forgot and I'm lazy lol

Comment: It's possible that there was a bug in the alpha version which is causing your problem. That's why you should always make sure you're using the latest released version before posting questions!

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a bug in the Alpha version of Blender. It is fixed in the current release.